# matlab cell mode with vim/gvim

Tags: matlab, vim, cells

I want to run a cell using vim. however, using what I see here:

[How to implement MATLAB-like cell mode in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093306/how-to-implement-matlab-like-cell-mode-in-vim)

I get a matlab instance starting, running and then closing. Is it possible to to this like it would be on a real matlab? ie I have a vim on one side and matlab on the other (open all the time), and by a vim command I get the cell to run on the matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether this is exactly what you want, but you might want to browse through these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739409/matlab-on-cmd-winxp)